# selecting an option for auditing purposes

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm designing a table to audit language (currently there are 15) selection of users on my website. I have two table style and coding to with them but I need your expertises to select one over another so please tell me which is better. Open for other options if you have any.

Thanks

**OPTION 1)** New record gets inserted into table after user's language selection. There will be many records.

**TABLE**

```
language - varchar(20) - Not Null
```

**CODE**

```
insert into table (language) values ('english');
```

**OPTION 2)** Value of relevant language column gets increased by 1 after user's language selection. There will be only one record.

**TABLE**

```
id         - char(1) - default '1'
language_x - int(11) - Unsigned
language_y - int(11) - Unsigned
language_z - int(11) - Unsigned
...
...
```

**CODE**

```
update table SET language_x = language_x + 1 where id = '1';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you expand option 1 to include (at least) user_name, id and selection_date columns plus a primary key and anything else you think may be useful. Gives you flexibility in analysing the data, you may only be interested in the number of users selecting a particular language now, but you will have other needs later.

Answer (score 0):

I too suggest option 1. You do not need to alter table later, unlike option 2, when one more language need to be supported. Further, in option 2, the update statement itself has to be changed for column name every time count for a different language has to be updated.